# Git wont let me change branches. Creates index.lock file and then hangs until I CTRL-C to kill it

Tags: git, version-control, branch

To be clear. I delete the index.lock file to begin with. But whenever I try to checkout my master branch, it then creates the index.lock file and won't let me switch.

Comment: Creation of index.lock is normal and prevents multiple operations from corrupting the repo; it would be deleted on completion of the operation.  So this probably has nothing to do with why the checkout is hanging.  Some key info is missing, but I think we don't even know enough to know what it is that's missing.  For a start, did anything unusual happen to the repo shortly before this behavior started?

Comment: What does `git status` state? Normally that´s a good point to start with. `git branch -av` is another option. Please add info.

Comment: First, please check you are nor execute multiple commands concurrently in the same repo. Then you can also try to use latest version of git bash.

Comment: And what if you delete the index.lock and switch branch again?